# Sending SequenceReset to acceptor

Tags: java, quickfix

I'm trying to see what QF/j can handle out of the box and tried sending a SequenceReset. however all the QF/J acceptor on the other end sends back is a regect message.

```
Session.sendToTarget(FixOrders.createSequenceReset(), sessionId);


public static SequenceReset createSequenceReset() {
       return new SequenceReset();
    }
```

any ideas?

Comment: have you tried setting the sequence reset in the config file. If so you do not have to code it, the engine does it itself.

Comment: @robthewolf thx, but I put in these ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
ForceResync=Y, and the sequence numbers are not effected after running this code **socketInitiator.stop();
   Thread.sleep(1000);
   socketInitiator.start();**

Comment: Is the acceptor yours or someoneelses?

Comment: @robthewolf its mines :)

Comment: @robthewolf btw, I would like to visit tel Aviv sometime, what is the finance work like down there?

Comment: if the acceptor is yours then the acceptor should be receiving the reset on log on and handling it.  This is not the place to discuss work and travel, sorry.

Comment: There are many reasons why a message might be rejected. What is the reject description?